# Effect size in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

I want to make this symbol (specifically the `'` after the `c`) but I cannot find it:[image]

Comment: In math mode, a `'` places a superscripted prime on the variable.  Likewise, `^prime` will do so, as well.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: So, `$H_0:c'3=0$` would be recommended.  If eliminating the space about the colon were important, then `$H_0{:}c'3=0$`.  If also making the prime larger were important, then `$H_0{:}c^{\displaystyle\prime}3=0$`.

Comment: Can you give some context or some place where the symbol appears?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- I assume you mean `^{\prime}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, I realized the typo too late to correct it.